# Uniqueness of continuity equation

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, reference-request

We consider the continuity equation
$$
\partial_t\rho(t, x) + \partial_x (v(x)\rho(t, x)) = 0, \quad \rho(0, x) = \rho_0(x)
$$
where $t\in [0, T]$, $T>0$, $x \in \mathbb{R}$, $v \in C^1(\mathbb{R})$ is Lipschitz and $\rho_0 \in L^1(\mathbb{R}) \cap L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$. I would like to know if you have a reference for uniqueness of the *weak solution* this equation.

I know that there are many uniqueness results for similar regularity (I am sure that for $v \in L^\infty(\mathbb{R})$ there is one, although it is very technical) but I can't seem to find one for this, although there are literally hundreds of variants of this equation in the literature.

I'd be grateful for help.